How to get the scheduler's last run date from a Scheduled Task item in Sitecore
I'm working with Sitecore's scheduler to create news items programmatically. However, I'm stuck on a scenario where I need to retrieve the scheduler's last run date from the CMS.
Is there any way to get the scheduler's last run date from the CMS?


When you are trying to read Last run field from the schedule item, are you getting some issue. Can you please elaborate the issue a little more to suggest the appropriate solution.

Sitecore's API provides a straightforward way to check when a scheduled task was last executed using the scheduleItem.LastRun property.
Here's how you can retrieve this information from your scheduled task:
public async void Execute(Item[] items, Sitecore.Tasks.CommandItem commandItem, Sitecore.Tasks.ScheduleItem scheduleItem)
{

       DateTime lastRunDate = scheduleItem.LastRun;
       Log.Info("Getting schedualr lastRunDate:" + lastRunDate, lastRunDate);
}

Hope this help!!

Thanks Praveen this code is working fine for me.

Glad to hear that

You can read the last run time for the scheduled task inside the command, using LastRun property as below.
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

public void Execute(Item[] items, Sitecore.Tasks.CommandItem commandItem, Sitecore.Tasks.ScheduleItem scheduleItem)
{
   var lastRunServerTime = DateUtil.ToServerTime(scheduleItem.LastRun);
}

Since the dates in Sitecore are stored in UTC Timezone, you can convert the time retrieved using LastRun property on the schedule item to server timezone using DateUtil extension as above.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

You can read last run from schedule item which is passed as a parameter in Execute method in scheduler class
public void Execute(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] items, Sitecore.TasksCommandItem command, Sitecore.TasksScheduleItem schedule)
{
  var lastruntime = schedule.LastRun ;
}

Hope this helps !!!
